# Analog of "until" command like in GDB for WinDbg or easy way to leave loop in WinDbg?

Tags: debugging, windbg

Currently I press right mouse button to select `"Copy file path to clipboard"` menu. Next left click to source line until where execute code, outside loop (this line number indicated in bottom right corner of WinDbg).

Next in command prompt I set breakpoint (by inserting from clipboard path to file and typing line number, which read from status bar):

```
bp `d:\home\devel\plugin\plugin-svn\common\win-gui-admin.c:788`
```

This seems too complicate. In GDB for leaving loops resurved command `until`. Any way to do this in WinDbg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F7 gives you the "Run to Cursor" command, which I think does what you're looking for. Just put the cursor on whatever source line you want and then hit F7.

-scott

Comment: Thanks! I use WinDbg some time and don't observe "Run to cursor" button (F7 or Ctrl+F10).

Answer (score 1):

again a very late answer but one can use source level syntax in windbg

`.lines` to enable src line support
`l+*` to enable all src options
`lsf` to load src file
`ls from,to` to inspect src lines from current src file
`lsc` to show current src file
`` `module!srcfile:linenum` `` to denaote any line from any src file (`src syntax needs to be wrapped in grave accents not single quotes)`

here is a sample walkthrough

```
jmpouttaloo:\>dir /b
jmpouttaloo.cpp

jmpouttaloo:\>type jmpouttaloo.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0;
    while (i++ < 100)
    {
        while (j++ < 100)
        {
            while(k++ < 100)
            {
                l++;
            }
            l++;
        }
        l++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",l);
    return 0;
}
jmpouttaloo:\>cl /Zi /nologo jmpouttaloo.cpp
jmpouttaloo.cpp

jmpouttaloo:\>dir /b *.exe
jmpouttaloo.exe

jmpouttaloo:\>jmpouttaloo.exe
300
```

`.lines turns on src line support` in cdb (it is on by defaukt in windbg )
`l+*` enables all src line options
`lsf` load src file jmpouttaloo.cpp
`set a bp on main and run` the exe

```
jmpouttaloo:\>cdb -c ".lines;l+*; lsf jmpouttaloo.cpp; bp jmpouttaloo!main;g" jmpouttaloo.exe
```

stepping with p steps one src line per step
in 6 steps we land inside the innermost while loop
now we want to get out of each loop systematically

`ls start , count` shows the src lines from start number to startnumber+count

to run until we get to certain src line

do g graveaccent  colon linenumber graveaccent

the complete src line syntax as follows

```
graveaccent modulename! filename : linenumber graveaccent
```

first run

```
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.lines;l+*; lsf jmpouttaloo.cpp; bp jmpouttaloo!main;g'


Breakpoint 0 hit
>    3: {
0:000> p
>    4:     int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0;
0:000>
>    5:     while (i++ < 100)
0:000>
>    7:         while (j++ < 100)
0:000>
>    9:             while(k++ < 100)
0:000>
>   11:                 l++;
0:000>
>   12:             }
0:000>
>    9:             while(k++ < 100)
```

we are in loop line 12 back to line 9 we need to exit out of this loop at line 13

```
0:000> ls 13,6   view src lines from line number 13 to 18 (6 lines )

13:             l++;
14:         }
15:         l++;
16:     }
17:     printf("%d\n",l);
18:     return 0;

0:000> dv  view locals we have stepped only once so all locals must be 1

          j = 0n1
          l = 0n1
          k = 0n1
          i = 0n1

0:000> g `:13` lets get out of innermost loop and look at the locals
>   13:             l++;
0:000> dv  
              j = 0n1
              l = 0n100 <-------
              k = 0n101 <-------------
              i = 0n1

0:000> g `:15` getting out of second innermost loop and inspect locals
>   15:         l++;
0:000> dv
              j = 0n101
              l = 0n200
              k = 0n200
              i = 0n1
0:000> g `:17` getting out of all loops   and inspect locals
>   17:     printf("%d\n",l);
0:000> dv
              j = 0n200
              l = 0n300
              k = 0n200
              i = 0n101
0:000> p
300    <--------------- output of printf 
>   18:     return 0;
0:000>
```

second run

```
another jig this time we break on line 15 straight without even loading the src


jmpouttaloo:\>cdb -c ".lines;g `jmpouttaloo!jmpouttaloo.cpp:15`;dv;q" jmpouttaloo.exe | grep -A 4 "j ="
              j = 0n101
              l = 0n200
              k = 0n200
              i = 0n1
quit:

jmpouttaloo:\>
```

Comment: Thanks for interest to question! +1